# Video card types and identification in Windows?

Tags: graphics-card

How many types of video cards do exist?

I was looking in desktop properties->settings->advanced->adapter and it said DAC type: internal.

What does 'internal' mean? Which are the other types of DACs?

Comment: how do you want to define *types* of video cards?  by interface (ISA, VLB, PCI, AGP, PCIe)? by GPU (radeon x, radeon y, radeon z, geforce a, geforce b, geforce c, voodoo 1, voodoo 3...)? by available memory?  by GPU capabilities (OpenGL, DirectX 5, DirectX 8, DirectX 10, Shader 1.0, Shader 2.0)? by... umm... what else is there...

Answer (score 0):

There are three main types of video card commonly in use.

- [PCI Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express)
- [AGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_Graphics_Port)
- [PCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI)

PCI Express is the most current, and fastest, of the video cards. If possible, you will likely want to install a PCI express video card.

[DAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) means that Digital-to-Analog Converter, converts digital signals to analog signals. [Types of DACs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter#DAC_types) are

- the pulse-width modulator
- Oversampling DACs or interpolating DACs
- the binary-weighted DAC
- the R-2R ladder DAC
- the thermometer-coded DAC and
- Hybrid DACs